# Gradlew build not working

Tags: spring, maven, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

When I'm trying to clean my project with `./gradlew clean` it works, but
the `./gradlew build` won't work. I tried a few repositories, but it can't resolve the Spring dependencies.

Here is the `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'hello'
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.json:json:20141113')
    compile('com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.8.1')
    compile('org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.2')
    compile('org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter')
    compile('org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter:1.1.0.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.social:spring-social-core')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}
```

And here the exception:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web: because no repositories are defined.
  Required by:
      :hello:unspecified
> Cannot resolve external dependency org.json:json:20141113 because no repositories are defined.
  Required by:
      :hello:unspecified
> Cannot resolve external dependency com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.8.1 because no repositories are defined.
  Required by:
      :hello:unspecified
> Cannot resolve external dependency org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.2 because no repositories are defined.
  Required by:
      :hello:unspecified
> Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter:1.1.0.RELEASE because no repositories are defined.
  Required by:
      :hello:unspecified
> Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter:1.1.0.RELEASE because no repositories are defined.
  Required by:
      :hello:unspecified
> Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.social:spring-social-core: because no repositories are defined.
  Required by:
      :hello:unspecified
```

I thought the maven repo is enough but it keeps failing I also tried it with `jcenter()`. Im working on a ubuntu 14.04 VM.

**SOLVED:**

As Michael said in the comments I had to add a version for the dependency:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.3.RELEASE')
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring repositories before dependencies?

Comment: yes still this exception:   `Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web`

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to apply the spring-boot Gradle plugin for the managed dependencies to work. See any of the Spring Boot Gradle examples for details.

Comment: You haven't specified a version for this dependency. Try `compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.3.RELEASE'`.

Comment: @Michael Thanks that solved it!

Comment: @julien Great, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare repositories before dependencies. And second, replace

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
```

with

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.3.RELEASE')
```

because the former doesn't contain a version.